# Clojure - using specter to transform a nested data structure, replacing one node with several

Tags: clojure, tree, transform, specter

I'm using [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) to transform nested data structures in Clojure, but I haven't got the hang of it yet. In particular, I'm trying to create a transformation that will find an item - at any depth - that matches a predicate, and replace it will several items.

```clj
[:top
 [:arbitrary 1 2
  [:nesting
   2
   3
   [:needle] ; <-- the thing to find
   ]]]

-->

[:top
 [:arbitrary 1 2
  [:nesting
   2
   3
   [:n1] [:n2] [:n3]  ; <-- 3 items inserted in the place of 1
   ]]]
```

What I can't figure out is how to splice the replacement items into the parent vector, i.e., how to replace one item with three items, and not with one item containing three children.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this using Specter, but here's a function to do it with clojure.zip:

```
(defn splice-replace [zipper smap]
  (loop [loc zipper]
    (if (z/end? loc)
      (z/root loc)
      (recur
       (z/next
        (if-let [sub (smap (z/node loc))]
          (reduce (comp z/right z/insert-right)
                  (z/replace loc (first sub))
                  (rest sub))
          loc))))))
```

You can call it with a zipper of your data structure and a map from values you want to replace to a sequence of their replacement values to be spliced into their position:

```
(def zipper
  (z/vector-zip [:top
                 [:arbitrary 1 2
                  [:nesting 2 3 [:needle]]]]))

(splice-replace zipper {[:needle] [[:n1] [:n2] [:n3]]})
 => [:top [:arbitrary 1 2 [:nesting 2 3 [:n1] [:n2] [:n3]]]]

(splice-replace zipper {[:nesting 2 3 [:needle]] (range 3 10)})
=> [:top [:arbitrary 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Comment: Although it's not specter this does what I need

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn replace-needle [input replacement]
    (let [needle-parent?     #(= % [:needle])
          NEEDLE-PARENT      (recursive-path
                                 [] p (cond-path
                                          #(and (vector? %) (some needle-parent? %)) [(continue-then-stay [ALL p])]
                                          vector? [ALL p]))
          inject-replacement (fn inject [x] (vec (mapcat #(if (needle-parent? %) replacement [%]) x)))]
        (transform [NEEDLE-PARENT] inject-replacement input)))


(let [input       [:top
                   [:arbitrary 1 2
                    [:nesting 2 3 [:needle]]]]
      replacement [[:n1] [:n2] [:n3]]]
    (replace-needle input replacement))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to create a path that would match the item itself, and then try and control how the replacement(s) were inserted in the parent, whereas you are searching for the item's parent and transforming that, which is easier to understand.
The solution doesn't always replace all occurrences:
    (let [input [:top [:needle]
                      [:a [:needle]]]
          replacement [1 2 3]]
      (replace-needle input replacement))

      ;->

      [:top 1 2 3 [:a [:needle]]]

Comment: Another approach would be finding a vector that contains `[:needle]`, and then the index of the `[:needle]`, and then use [`srange`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/wiki/List-of-Navigators#srange) to splice the new elements into the parent at that index. Is it possible to express "finding a vector that contains `[:needle]`, and then the index of the `[:needle]`" in Specter without the use of custom navigators?

Comment: I made it recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it should be possible to find a vector that contains `[:needle]`, and then the index of the `[:needle]`, and then use [`srange`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/wiki/List-of-Navigators#srange) to splice the new elements into the parent at that index, but I didn't find a way to do it using Specter.

Here's that same idea expressed using `clojure.walk`:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]])

(postwalk (fn [node]
            (if (and (vector? node)
                     (some (partial = [:needle]) node))
              (let [idx (.indexOf node [:needle])]
                (vec (concat (take idx node)
                             [[:n1] [:n2] [:n3]]
                             (drop (inc idx) node))))
              node))
          data)

;; => [:top [:arbitrary 1 2 [:nesting 2 3 [:n1] [:n2] [:n3]]]]
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea. My aim is to take a simple structure and progressively transform it into ooxml (for a Word document). In a previous life I'd probably have used XSLT and maybe there are better solutions than specter, but it looks too interesting not to try and learn it.

Comment: Specter should be usable. Nathan's talks are great. I've dabbled in it. My experience so far: for the usual cases the concise syntax is not worth the unfamiliarity for other developers. And for advanced cases I find it quite unreadable with things like custom navigators, multi-paths and terminals. In its defense, at my previous job we had a problem for which I wrote a unit test that seemed unsolvable in normal Clojure. My colleague got to work and in one day produced 10 lines of Specter code that solved it. A work of art.

Comment: Maybe with Specter you can create a custom `TreeWalker` like in the example from the [README](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter). :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the recursive-path and then uses srange-dynamic to update in place.  It does not feel great to do another linear search in the "inject/transformation" function but There does not appear to be any way to inject at the current location similar to BEGINNING or END.

```
(transform [(recursive-path [] RECURSE
                        (if-path sequential?
                          (if-path (selected? [ALL (pred= [:needle])])
                            STAY
                            [ALL  RECURSE])))]
       (fn inject [v]  (setval (srange-dynamic
                                #(.indexOf % [:needle])
                                (end-fn [_ start] (inc start)))
                               [[:n1] [:n2] [:n3]] v))
       [:top [:arbitrary 1 2 [:nesting 2 3 [:needle] :more]]])
```